# Opposite of "ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.auto_link"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

Is there any method do the opposite of what "auto_link()" does ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip_links()`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_links